# AngularJS ng-repeat duplicating elements

Tags: angularjs, associative-array, angularjs-ng-repeat

For some odd reason the code in this [jsfiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/WxmCf/1/) is duplicating the elements when iterating over an array of associative values. The input fields show the 3 names correctly but the fields are repeated 3 times for each name. What is more perplexing is that the `{{ p.name }}` shows a different value than the `ng-model="p.name"` on each iteration. The index shows 0, 1 and 2 three times each. Why would there be three iterations per element?

Controller:

```
var app=angular.module('myApp', []);

function MyCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.people = [
        { name:'Tom', age:5 }, 
        { name:'Dick', age:6 }, 
        { name:'Harry', age:7 }
];

}
```

HTML:

```
<div ng-controller="MyCtrl">
    <form> 
    <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="p in people">{{$index}}, {{$first}}, {{$middle}}, {{$last}}, {{p.name}}, {{p.age}}
            <input type="text" ng-model="p.name">
        </li>
    </ul>      
    </form>
</div>
```

Any thoughts on what is wrong with this code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have AngularJS included twice.

Once under "Frameworks & Extensions" and a 2nd time under "External Resources".

Comment: Thanks - that was it! I had copied someone else's jsfiddle code and mocked up.